# Query WHERE Only Alphabetic Characters

Tags: sql, excel, odbc, microsoft-query

I am trying to filter out data in my Excel sheet of customers for my company.
The three fields I need to by are `FIRST_NAME`, `LAST_NAME`, and `COMPANY_NAME`.

The rules are as follows:

- `FIRST_NAME` AND `LAST_NAME` must `NOT` be `NULL`
- `FIRST_NAME` AND `LAST_NAME` must be only alphabetic
- The above rules are irrelevant IF `COMPANY_NAME` is `NOT NULL`

So, just to reiterate to be clear.. A customer must have a `FIRST_NAME` AND a `LAST_NAME` (They cannot be missing one or both), BUT, if they have a `COMPANY_NAME` they are allowed to not have a `FIRST_NAME` and/or `LAST_NAME`.

Here's some example data and if they should stay in the data or not:

```
FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | COMPANY_NAME |         Good customer?
-----------|-----------|--------------|--------------------------------
   Alex    |  Goodman  |    AG Inc.   | Yes - All are filled out
   John    |  Awesome  |              | Yes - First and last are fine
   Cindy   |           |  Cindy Corp. | Yes - Company is filled out
           |           |   Blank Spa  | Yes - Company is filled out
           |           |              | No - Nothing is filled out
  Gordon   |  Mang#2   |              | No - Last contains non-alphabet
  Jesse#5  |  Levvitt  |    JL Inc.   | Yes - Company is filled out
  Holly    |           |              | No - No last or company names
```

Here is the query (With some fields in the `SELECT` clause removed):

```
SELECT VR_CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_ID, VR_CUSTOMERS.FIRST_NAME, VR_CUSTOMERS.LAST_NAME, VR_CUSTOMERS.COMPANY_NAME, ...
FROM DEV.VR_CUSTOMERS VR_CUSTOMERS
WHERE (
LENGTH(NAME)>4 AND
(UPPER(NAME) NOT LIKE UPPER('%delete%')) AND
(COMPANY_NAME IS NOT NULL OR (COMPANY_NAME IS NULL AND FIRST_NAME IS NOT NULL AND LAST_NAME IS NOT NULL AND FIRST_NAME LIKE '%^[A-z]+$%' AND LAST_NAME LIKE '%^[A-z]+$%'))
)
```

I've tried as well the regex of `'%[^a-z]%'`. I've tried `RLIKE` and `REGEXP`, instead of `LIKE`, and those did not seem to work either.

With the above query, the results only show records with a `COMPANY_NAME`.

Comment: you can create a custom function for this purpose. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10395393/6348498

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the issue using `REGEXP_LIKE` and the regex `^[A-z]+$`.

Here is the `WHERE` clause after this fix:

```
WHERE (
LENGTH(NAME)>4 AND
(UPPER(NAME) NOT LIKE UPPER('%delete%')) AND
(COMPANY_NAME IS NOT NULL OR (COMPANY_NAME IS NULL AND REGEXP_LIKE(FIRST_NAME, '^[A-z]+$') AND REGEXP_LIKE(LAST_NAME, '^[A-z]+$')))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're using MySQL given your mention of RLIKE and REGEXP. In that case, try this WHERE clause, that uses the [regular expression character class 'alpha'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html):

```
WHERE 
      COMPANY_NAME is not null    -- COMPANY_NAME being present is the higher priority pass condition 
  or  ( -- but if COMPANY_NAME is not present, then the following conditions must be satisfied 
           FIRST_NAME is not null 
       and FIRST_NAME REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]+' 
       and LAST_NAME is not null 
       and LAST_NAME REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]+' 
      )
```

Bear in mind that the not null check is redundant given the regular expression, so the WHERE clause would simplify itself to:

```
WHERE 
      COMPANY_NAME is not null    -- COMPANY_NAME being present is the higher priority pass condition 
  or  ( -- but if COMPANY_NAME is not present, then the following conditions must be satisfied 
           FIRST_NAME REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]+' 
       and LAST_NAME REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]+' 
      )
```

Comment: I don't think it's MySQL, I'm actually kind of unsure what it's using. Using REGEXP actually gives 'invalid relational operator' error.

Comment: Alpha was not working, and REGEXP was not working. I ended up getting it to work with: `(COMPANY_NAME IS NOT NULL OR (COMPANY_NAME IS NULL AND REGEXP_LIKE(FIRST_NAME, '^[A-z]+$') AND REGEXP_LIKE(LAST_NAME, '^[A-z]+$')))`

Comment: Good to hear that you got it working finally - and REGEXP_LIKE is apparently an Oracle condition, so that clarifies the mystery of your underlying database too!