# Combine IsNumeric and Right()

Tags: ms-access-2010

[image]

Trying to return field [doc] that have no letters.  Results are all over the place.

```
SELECT Right([doc],4) AS ex1, IsNumeric([ex1]) AS ex2
FROM stat_converted;
```

The query returns two fields as it should but not evaluating correctly.  Results with all numbers and others that are all letters are coming back as True(-1).

I also tried building a temp table and then applying IsNumeric to that with same results.

I also built a small test DB and the logic works so I am really confused.

Comment: Does `IsNumeric(Right([doc],4))` work? Can you show us some examples where it is giving what appears to be the wrong result?

Comment: Also, `IsNumeric` will match things like "2E+1" as that is a number in scientific format. Maybe `ex1 LIKE '####'` would be better as "#" stands for a digit.

Comment: I think I found the issue.  Lots of duplicates.  Give me a bit.

Comment: "0D00" is a valid number in scientific format. Although it isn't used much, it is the double-precision version of "0E00". I think the `LIKE '####'` clause will server you better than `IsNumeric`.

Comment: Andrew is you put your comment in as an answer I can mark it as solving the problem.  Still not sure why IsNumeric does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IsNumeric` will match things like "2E+1" (2 times ten to the power of 1, i.e. 20) as that is a number in scientific format. "0D88" is also a number according to `IsNumeric` because it is the double-precision (hence the "D") version of "0E88".

You could use `LIKE '####'` to match exactly four digits (0-9).

If you had more complex match requirements, say a variable quantity of digits, you would be interested in [Expressing basic Access query criteria as regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10395393/1115360).

Comment: I like the super simple _Like_ method.