# Access 10 sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, sql-like

I want to use `LIKE` operator in access 10 sql query with variable.

Example:

```
temporary variable var contains value bs
var = "bs"
```

I want to match every String that starts with value of temporary variable followed by zero or more numbers.

I am trying to fire the query:

```
select * from xyz where variety LIKE "@[tempvars]![var] + [0-9]*"
```

It is returning 0 records.
Thankz for the help.

Comment: It seems you are trying to use REGEX in your query which ms access doesn't support. You can , however, use a custom function: See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393087/expressing-basic-access-query-criteria-as-regular-expressions

Comment: _DO NOT USE this tag for Microsoft Access, use [ms-access] instead._

Comment: Null records is not a thing. Null is not zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refer to your tempvar outside of the quotes, and use `&` for concatenation:

```
select * from xyz where variety LIKE "@" & [tempvars]![var] & "[0-9]*"
```

This will return all records where `variety` starts with a literal `@`, then whatever is in `[tempvars]![var]`, then a number, and then any amount of characters.

Comment: Still returning 0 records. I have a record with bs01 entry .

Comment: That doesn't start with a literal `@`, does it?

Comment: Got it . Thank you very much . Very silly mistake. @Erik von Asmuth

Comment: when my temporary variable contains BS01 , it is returning 0 records. why is it so ?

Comment: but [0-9]* means zero or more occurrence. Right ?

Comment: Nope. Read my answer. Like I said, `[0-9]*` means ONE number, and then zero or more occurences of ANY character.

Comment: I don't know. I don't know your purpose. Also, like Jorge Campos said, this isn't regex. Pattern matching using `Like` is very limited.

Comment: I want to match every String that starts with value of temporary variable followed by zero or more numbers.

Comment: That's not possible. You need to specify the amount of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if that variety is available in your table or not. If that variety is available in your table then don't search with like operator and otherwise use like operator.