# Fuzzy Matching Based on Previous Matches in Access/Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, match, fuzzy-search, fuzzy

I have an excel list of 20-30 thousand company shipping locations that I use for work. There are two fields, one containing the ship to location name and a field I created to group them together, as there is no unique identifier. For example:

JACKS SPORT #345
JACKS SPORTING 763
RAYS BOATS ORLANDO FL
RAY BOAT FLORIDA
JACK SPORT WAREHOUSE

In my field, I create a common name, such as Jacks Sporting Goods and Rays Boats for above.

Every month a couple hundred new shipping locations are added and need to be matched with the rest of the list and any errors from previous matches found.

Looking for a way to fuzzy match based on all previous matches and variations that have already been made. So instead of trying to match against my Rays Boats, it would look at all the variations for Rays Boats in the first column and find new matches based on those hundreds of different ways it appeared previously.

I am building an Access database that uses this file and would love to integrate it into Access, but if I need to run it through excel first I will.

Any suggestions? I have tried the free fuzzy matching tool from Microsoft, but there is no way to use VBA to automate the process...

Answer (score 1):

All one can do is query with wildcards (i.e. * symbol)

I have done this quite a few times in projects where the data source is imperfect.  It takes some business know-how in terms of knowing how much should be literal versus wild.  Too much literal and you miss matches.  Too little literal and you get a lot of false positives.

Sometimes one has to do it in steps - and set up a check box for a human to then check the valid / invalid as part of the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having users enter the name into an MS Access form and want to query the name in real time, the most efficient way would be to use a wildcard query:

```
SELECT field_to_query 
FROM table_name
WHERE field_to_query LIKE "*text to search for*";
```

If responsiveness is not a priority (i.e., you only need to match entries up after the fact) you can also use a combination of [regular](http://bricestacey.com/2010/07/09/Regular-Expressions-in-MS-Access.html) [expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393087/expressing-basic-access-query-criteria-as-regular-expressions) and replacement functions to create a [stemming function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming).

You could even create a simplified [TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) method to compare each location with each new entered location. To do this, you would split all the words in all the names while keeping track of which name contains which words. Calculate term frequency (TF) by counting the number of times a given word appears in a location divided how many words are in the location. Calculate inverse document frequency (IDF) by dividing the number of locations divided by the number of locations containing the words. Then you use the TF-IDF scores you've calculated to identify the closest match. This is definitely the most involved and the slowest.